# SeekBar with minimum, maximum and negative values on android

Tags: android, seekbar, limits

I'm trying to create a SeekBar on android and I'd like to set its maximum and its minimum using both negative and positive values; for example I'd like to choose a minimum of 5 and a maximum of 150; I can do this and it's quite simple: you can subtract minValue from progress value and it's ok...

My problem is when I try to set a negative maximum and minimum.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: The math is no different for positive or negative values for the minimum and maximum. You just need to make the maximum be the highest value (i.e., "least negative").

Comment: Yes but I forgot to write I should also synchronize the progress value during the setting. I'm working on it; I'm at a good point and when I'll reach the solution I'll publish it here! Thanks for help.